# Elasticsearch Installation seems to hang

Tags: elasticsearch

when I start the Elasticsearch in local its tuck after loaded geoip database file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Xec.png)

Comment: You would need to give more information if you want to get help here, you can try to increase resource you allocated to the system.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors and code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

please don't post pictures of text, logs or code. They are difficult to read, impossible to search and replicate (if it's code), and some people may not be even able to see them

from what I can tell from the image, Elasticsearch has started and is ready to process requests. try to open `127.0.0.1:9200` in your browser, you should get a response